# Expressjs Error: Headers ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader

Tags: node.js, express

On my signup user account Express 4 app, I get this error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
```

Error occurs only when trying to sign up, with an existing email, then an existing username. (I get the flash messages as expected).

Signups using  unique emails and unique usernames work perfectly.

I learned that the error can be:
* error usually happens when people treat an async response inside an express route as a synchronous response and they end up sending data twice.*

I don't see where I'm sending the "data twice"

Thanks for help - Rob

> CODE

```
/**
 * GET /signup
 * Signup page.
 */
exports.getSignup = (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    return res.redirect('/account');
  }
  res.render('account/signup', {
    title: 'Create Account'
  });
};

/**
 * POST /signup
 * Create a new local account.
 */

exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
  req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.check('username', 'username must be 6-50 lower case characters, only letters and numbers, no spaces allowed.').isAlphanumeric().isLowercase().len(6);
  req.sanitize('email').normalizeEmail({
    gmail_remove_dots: false
  });

  const errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    req.flash('errors', errors);
    return res.redirect('/signup');
  }

  const user = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    // password: req.body.password
  });

  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  }, (err, existingUser) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (existingUser) {
      req.flash('errors', {
        msg: 'Account with that email address already exists.'
      });
      return res.redirect('/signup');
    }
  });

  User.findOne({
    username: req.body.username
  }, (err, existingUser) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (existingUser) {
      req.flash('errors', {
        msg: 'Account with that username name already exists.'
      });
      return res.redirect('/signup');
    }

  });

  user.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      // doesn't wokr either res.redirect('/account');
      return res.redirect('/account');
    });
  });
};
```

** NOTE **
- my code started with
- https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter/blob/731ec259c3d17fbee8171f2d280cbdf283177b76/controllers/user.js
- I added the username to the signup form

Comment: You have three callbacks working in parallel. This is the same async problem as other people have.

Comment: How do I have only one callback... and keep the error checking for username/password. I'm kinda new to Expressjs.

Comment: The three things that are running at the same time is the code in the two `User.findOne()`s and the code in `user.save()`. You can do three things to fix the problem: nest the functions inside each other; use promises that are chained one after another; or use async/await together with promises. You can see an example of using callbacks vs. promises [here](http://erikaybar.name/using-es6-promises-with-mongoosejs-queries/).

Comment: Thanks for advise. I did nest the functions inside of each other, this seems to work, although it sometimes redirects to /login - I'll debug that.  Here is the nested version https://gist.github.com/mrmccormack/b1d5f9021281f3d2a20b38bce794c6b2 

I would like to try promise solution, but don't know where to start. Hackathon uses bluebird.  Any help getting me started would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I  have it working, using $or: in the findOne statement. (my Gist, "nested" solution didn't seem to always work)

```
User.findOne({$or: [
      {email: req.body.email},
      {username: req.body.username}
      ]
      }).exec(function(err, existingUser){
```

**but I do wonder if I should be using a promise with this solution?**

---

#### Full code here.

```
/**
 * POST /signup
 * Create a new local account.
 */


exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
  req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.check('username', 'username must be 6-50 lower case characters, only letters and numbers, no spaces allowed.').isAlphanumeric().isLowercase().len(6);
  req.sanitize('email').normalizeEmail({
    gmail_remove_dots: false
  });

  const errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    req.flash('errors', errors);
    return res.redirect('/signup');
  }

  const user = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    // password: req.body.password
  });

  User.findOne({$or: [
      {email: req.body.email},
      {username: req.body.username}
      ]
      }).exec(function(err, existingUser){

    // console.log('existingUser.email ' + existingUser.email)
    // console.log('existingUser.email ' + existingUser.username)

    if (!existingUser){
      console.log('now existing user was found');
      console.log('no users with that email NOR phone exist');
      user.save((err) => {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }
          res.redirect('/account');
        });
      });
    } else if (existingUser.email == req.body.email) {
        console.log('user already exists with EMAIL ');
        req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Account with that EMAIL  already exists.' });
        return res.redirect('/signup');
      }
      else if (existingUser.username = req.body.username){
        console.log('user already exists with USERNAME.');
        req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Account with that USERNAME  already exists.' });
        return res.redirect('/signup');

      }
      else {
      // nothing
        return res.redirect('/signup');
      }

  });

}; // END exports.postSignup {}
```